# HoloLens 2 failing to provide Immersive AR/VR experience for WebXR

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, virtual-reality, hololens, webxr

I have a basic WebXR application built using A-Frame. It is the standard AR example with a plane and a sphere, cube and cylinder placed on the plane.
[image: WebXR Application]

I have it running in my laptop and I am accessing it from my HoloLens 2. Both are in same network. I could access the URL from Edge.
When I click on VR button in edge, HoloLens is not overlaying the AR objects on the environment. Instead, I see the objects in black mesh like screen.
[image: Object rendered in Black mesh screen on HoloLens 2]

I could view the 3D content in 3D Viewer app in HoloLens, but when I try to use WebXR app launched from Edge, it does not work.

I could make the same app work in my windows and mobile as intended but not in HoloLens 2.
I tried resetting the device, checked the browser version and WebXR compatibility, tried different examples from three.js.
Please share solution for this problem of not getting immersive experience on HoloLens 2 for WebXR applications hosted on the Desktop on the same network.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the Developer tools? Have you tried these samples - [WebXR - Samples (immersive-web.github.io)](https://immersive-web.github.io/webxr-samples/)?

Comment: It showed VR and AR support detected but on trying examples it didn't overlay AR objects on the environment. It worked as it worked for our A-Frame Application. No error messages in Developer Tools as well but there was this statement "three.webglrenderer cant change size while vr device is presenting"

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, my environment is HoloLens OS **20348.1506**, Microsoft Edge **110.0.1587.63**. Please update to the same version as mine or the latest version for testing.
Also, please check whether Microsoft Edge's **Settings->Cookies and site permissions->All permissions->Virtual reality** is enabled.

Comment: Thank You!
OS version : 20348.1542
Microsoft Edge version : 110.0.1587.63
VR is enabled in the browser
"Ask when a site wants to use your virtual reality devices and data (recommended)
Will block if turned off" is enabled.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, it looks like a bug, please report it via Feedback Hub - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/hololens/hololens-feedback.